# Hide Specific Navigation Menu Items using Page Variation ( Audience ) in Salesforce Communtiy

Tags: community, navigation

We decided to go with one Salesforce Community for 3 different Partner Types.
All of the Partners should be able to see different tabs, and it's working correctly with tabs.

In the one case, we have Navigation Menu Label ( Sales ) with for Items ( Lead, Account, Opportunity, Contact ). When we hide these objects to the partners, they are still able to see Sales Navigation Menu Label, and not able to click on it.

Is there any solution on how to hide Navigation Menu Label ( Sales tab )
[image]

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't hide labels, you can only "hide" navigation menu items that are of the type "Salesforce Object" via permissions. To get around this you'd need to either put all the objects in the top navigation, or create a custom component for the navigation.

Comment: I believe if you have a custom community page and you set up audience targeting so that there isn't a default version, it will be hidden from users unless they fall within that audience.